# openCL strange NaNs occurrence

Tags: opencl, nan

I've run into a very strange behaviour with my openCL code again. In my code I have nodes, which are updated with some incremental learning rule which uses a gaussian to determine the weight. 
The strange behaviour I am having now, is that when I only do a few update cycles, everything seems to work okay, however if I do more cycles, I sometimes start to get NaNs in my nodes.

The even funnier thing however is, that once I start to look for the cause of the NaNs by placing an "if (isnan(x))" in there, I do not get NaNs anymore.

I know that as a dirty hack I could just leave that test in there and hope that it will always prevent the NaNs from occuring, but I do not like that false solution, and I would really like to know where those come from.

All I am doing is some products and sums, as well as one gaussian (meaning exp). All the initials values are definetly not NaNs and in the next cycle only the results from the previous are used.

Where they could come from, or even just why they do not appear when I try to look for them?

Comment: Have you tried checking it with if (x == x)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just tried if(x!=x) instead of isnan(x) and it behaves the same, meaning that with the test (even though inside the body of the if, I only print a notification), I do not get NaNs without I do though.

Comment: Can you post the code that is generating the NaNs?

Comment: Code will be useful indeed.

Comment: Well I found the source of the NaNs, my covariance for the gaussian was getting too small. I do not know though why the testing sometimes (not always) prevented that. Thanks for your help anyways.